# How to move right toolbar window in front of the bottom toolbar window in intelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've 2 tool windows open in addition to the main Editor window, Terminal and debug. The terminal window is on the right sidebar and debug window is on the bottom sidebar.

The problem is that bottom sidebar is in front of the right sidebar. But I want the right bar to be in the front.

How can I change this configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the **Widescreen tool window layout** option in File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance:

[image: widescreen]